# OutOfMemoryError android : converting bitmap to string (imposiable?)

Tags: android, image, bitmap, imageview

i'm so fustrated from this little thing that for some reason just doesn't work out...i don't really know what else to do. the pictures im trying to add are been selected by my gallery..(the last thing i've checked was 1024X768 and 32 color bit)

```
ImageButton img;
private static final int SELECTED_PICTURE = 1;
String picPathFile;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_channel);

    img = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, SELECTED_PICTURE);
        }
    });


    // defines the button functionality

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backToMenu);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        // defines to move to menu activity when button is pressed
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent showImageIntent = new Intent(AddChannelActivity.this, ShowPreviewChannel.class);

            Bitmap selected_image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picPathFile);

            showImageIntent.putExtra("pic_file", picPathFile);
            showImageIntent.putExtra("c_name", name);
            showImageIntent.putExtra("c_id", "777");
            startActivity(showImageIntent);

            //newImage.recycle(); // where do i put it??
            //newImage = null;
            //selected_image.recycle();
            //selected_image = null;
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch(requestCode) {
        case SELECTED_PICTURE: {
            if (requestCode == SELECTED_PICTURE) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);

                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

                cursor.close();

                picPathFile = picturePath;
                have_picture = true;

            }
            break;
        }
        default: break;
    }
}



 Intent intent = getIntent();


// the rellvant part from the show preview class
 Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if(bundle!= null){
        String picturePath = intent.getStringExtra("pic_file");

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray(); // HERE~!!!!! out of memory
}
```

ive tried everything....please help me :/

i saw the baos size is 7193767

Comment: Please describe what you need to do. Considering your code it is not really clear.

Comment: I'm trying to encode an image to string (to be sent out for a server)

and when i get it from the server ill decode it and show it on my app

Comment: Your requestCode == SELECTED_PICTURE is broken on most Android devices. [A Uri is not a file](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html). You cannot reliably get access to a file path to something you get from a `ContentProvider`, as the data might not be in a file, or it might not be in a file that you have access to. Use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to access the contents of the image. Beyond that, do not waste memory reading in the image in the first activity, since you are not using it.

Comment: but how do i do it?
            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

this is the problematic side you say?

Comment: can you show me how to do it? i don't quite follow you

Comment: Do not use Bitmap and BitmapFactory. Instead read the file directly in byte b[].

Comment: What do you mean exactly with 'converting bitmap to string'?

Comment: I got it to work..all i needed is to minimize the size of the pictures